# Anti Virus sending alerts in Sharepoint Search folder

Tags: 2010, search, sharepoint-server, folder, anti-virus

We have implemented SharePoint 2010 search, our antivirus generating following:

```
fltxxxxx_xxxx.csv as W32.EICAR.15lc
```

And location of the file is

`C:\Users\svc_sp_search\AppData\Local\Temp\gthrsvc_OSearch14\`

Can anyone please tell what this file is and how this file could be generated in SharePoint Search Temp Folder?

How this EICAR test file came to this temp folder? Is SharePoint creating it at this location? Crawl is copying?

Answer (score 1):

It's a false-positive. There are exclusions to antivirus that need to be added: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952167

> ...
>
> - Drive:\Users\ **account that the search service is running as** \AppData\Local\Temp
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of expected behavior, Antiviruse(file-Level AntiVirus) scan cause a lot of issue if you forget to exclude certain folders from scanning. I recently witness an issue in our farm where i forget to exclude the sync folder and User Profile Sync took 18 hours for incremental.
Not only exclude the search account folder but you have to exclude all below folders as well for better performance.

**SharePoint Foundation 2010**

- Drive:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
  Extensions
- Drive:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
  Files
- Drive: \Users\ServiceAccount\AppData\Local\Temp\WebTempDir

Note The WebTempDir folder is a replacement for the FrontPageTempDir folder.

- Drive:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint
- Drive:\Users\account that the search service is running
  as\AppData\Local\Temp

Note The search account creates a folder in the Gthrsvc_spsearch4 Temp folder to which it periodically has to write.

- Drive:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles
- Drive:\Windows\Syswow64\LogFiles

Note If you use a specific account for SharePoint services or application pools identities, you may also have to exclude the following folders:

- Drive:\Users\ServiceAccount\AppData\Local\Temp
- Drive:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp

**SharePoint 2010 Server**

- Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Data

(This folder is used for the indexing process. If the Index files are configured to be located in a different folder, you also have to exclude that location.)

- Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Logs
- Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Bin
- Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization
  Service
- Any location in which you decided to store the disk-based binary
  large object (BLOB) cache (for example, C:\Blobcache)

Note If you have SharePoint Server 2010, these folders should be excluded in addition to the folders that are listed in the "SharePoint Foundation 2010" section.